# Знаки препинания при обособленном приложении

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

Он и вспыльчив был, и капризен, и занудлив, и авторитарно-наставителен; но огромный сычёвский опыт -(?) сын ошибок-"рецидивисток" в его случае -(?) в сочетании с абсолютно нетривиальным подходом к решению поставленных перед ним задач заставлял хозяина фирмы терпеть этого уже немолодого анфан террибль на (в) должности главного инженера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он и вспыльчив был, и капризен, и занудлив, и авторитарно-наставителен; но огромный сычёвский опыт - сын ошибок-"рецидивисток" в его случае - в сочетании с абсолютно нетривиальным подходом к решению поставленных перед ним задач заставлял хозяина фирмы терпеть этого уже немолодого "анфан террибль" на  должности главного инженера.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Обособление приложения с помощью тире (добавочный характер сообщения).

2) Кавычки ставятся или не ставятся (авторский вариант).

3) Лучше "на должности", а вообще используются оба варианта, сравнить:

а) работать на должности, сменить на должности, оставаться на должности, служба на должности

б) пребывать в должности, работать в должности, утвердить в должности, опт работы в должности.

Comment: "Кавычки ставятся или не ставятся (авторский вариант)" где именно:  ошибок-"рецидивисток" или "анфан террибль"?

Comment: Спасибо, Vera !

Comment: "Анфан террибль" пишут по-разному, возможная причина:1) слова непривычные, малоупотребительные, на которые автор хочет обратить внимание; 2) слова, представляющие собой малоизвестные термины.

Comment: Ошибок-"рецидивисток" : слова, употребленные в условном значении (применительно к ситуации или контексту).

Comment: Б  л  а  г  о  д  а  р  ю  !